# Magento webservice call error - Required parameter is missing

Tags: php, web-services, magento

I'm using below code to call a magento webservice. This code was working fine last month. But now it's giving an error - "Required parameter is missing"

```
try {
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1', array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 120));

    $session = $proxy->login(array(
        'username' => "username",
        'apiKey' => "apikey"
    ));
    $sessionId = $session->result;

    $filters = array(
       'sku' => array('like'=>'zol%')
    );

    $products = $proxy->catalogProductList(array("sessionId" => $sessionId, "filters" => $filters));

    echo '<h1>Result</h1>';
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($products);
    echo '</pre>';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
    echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

The error message has the code `invalid_request_param` that is thrown only if the username is empty or if the apiKey is empty. See `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::login` or if some parameters are wrong when using the WS-I compliance. See `Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Handler::prepareArgs`.
This should be a good place to start debugging.
First make sure the login works. Most probably it does. Then add `Mage::log($params)` and `Mage::log($args)` in the `prepareArgs` method and checj `var/syste.log` to see how your parameters arrive in that method. Maybe you get an idea of what is wrong.

[/EDIT]

According to the WSDL the `catalogProductList` method takes 3 parameters:

```
<message name="catalogProductListRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="filters" type="typens:filters"/>
    <part name="storeView" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

and when using WS-I complience you still have 3 parameters but the 3rd is not mandatory:

```
<xsd:element name="catalogProductListRequestParam">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="filters" type="typens:filters" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="store" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

You are sending only one parameter. An array with 2 elements.
I suggest trying this like this (not sure if I'm right):

```
$products = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filters);
```

or maybe

```
$products = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filters, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try complex_filter like this

```
$filters = array(
  'complex_filter' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'sku',
        'value' => array('key' => 'like', 'value' => 'zol%')
    )
  )
);

$products = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filters);
```